# Compilation Error when Compiling Kount Extension on Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1

I've installed the Kount Magento 2 Extension on Magento 2.1.3 and I am running into an RuntimeException when running the compile command:

```
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1     sec 74.8 MiB
     [RuntimeException]                                                                                  
  Source class "\Kount_Log_Binding_Nop" for "Kount_Log_Binding_NopLogger"     generation does not exist.  

setup:di:compile
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've contacted Kount but they can't seem to pinpoint the error since they use a third party for the extension development.

Comment: As the development team of this extension, I'd like to be of any help I can.  Jeremey, from the post below reached out to us directly and I see you're issue is still open.  Do you still need guidance / assistance ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this issue. After a bit of sleuthing, I did eventually track down that these classes are part of the PHP SDK libraries available at https://support.kount.com/Developer_Resources/Software_Development_Kits_(SDKs).

<s>Despite being mentioned in their documentation, the packages are not composer-ready just yet. The developers, [Swarming Technology](https://swarmingtech.com/), have been notified about this. Hopefully the documentation will be updated to include the necessary steps or perhaps the SDK files can be included in the module download.</s>

**Update:** The official documentation now includes steps to install these SDK files. However, they now also support a Github page and Composer repository which you can use instead. This option is not included in their documentation. I've updated my below answers to include this.

---

Here are your options to install the Kount SDK libraries:

### Integrated

To include the API files within the module directory (in order to keep it self-contained), add the SDK library files (including the autoload.php and settings.ini) somewhere, such as lib/Kount/, within the Swarming/Kount directory.

Within the Swarming/Kount/registration.php file, add a

```
require_once('lib/Kount/autoload.php');
```

The SDK API files should now load.

### Autoloader (should work composer or composerless)

### Composer

Kount now supports a composer package installation of their SDK.

Simply use `composer require kount/kount-ris-php-sdk` in your project or add `"kount/kount-ris-php-sdk": "^6.5"` to your `composer.json` `"require"` section and run `composer update`.

### Composerless

The magento-composer-autoloader package (required by all versions of Magento 2) does include Magento 1.x-style autoloading within the /lib/internal directory.

Add the SDK files under /lib/internal/Kount/(Log|Ris|SimpleLogger|Util)

You may need to run `composer dump-autoload`, but the classes should now be autoloaded.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for playing a little bit of deep dive Google work to get in touch with us! For future users, If anyone has issues, contact our support desk @ support@swarmingtech.com and we'll be glad to help out!

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Yurii did let me know that /lib/internal works automatically. I swear I had tried this and it didn't work, but it appears to be working now. I've updated my answer to reflect this.